# How to rotate Highcharts Meteogram Weather Symbols around its center?

Tags: jquery, html, css, highcharts

I have tried rotation attribute, it rotates images from (0,0) pixels, may be from `translateX`, and `translateY`, not sure.

Can I rotate image without affecting its position?

Comment: I do not use highcharts, so YMMV; basically you'll need to change the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin to the center of the image (X:naturalWidth/2,Y:naturalHeight/2) see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement

Comment: Thanks @flowtron , Can you please help me.. here is sample code..  (on  line number : 271 , I wrote 'rotation:90,' , because I want to rotate is by 90degree , but its position got chaged.   )http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-meteogram/         I want to achieve  this kind of around center rotation   http://output.jsbin.com/owuyiq/